# Unexpected Long Running Post Request | Heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku

This post route is consistently taking longer than 30 seconds to complete.

For the life of me I'm not sure why that would be. Is there a way to update my code to ensure the post request completes quicker? Any idea whats causing the huge delay?

**Update: Our site has been getting significantly more traffic so it could be an issue with our Heroku Dynos being set to Hobby. Thoughts?**

```
    router.post("/updateAccount", usernameToLowerCase, async function(req, res){
    
    if (req.user) {
    
    await User.findOne({username: req.body.currentUser}, function(err, user) {
    return done(err);
    }
    
    user.username = req.body.username;
    user.password = req.body.password;
    user.accountUpdated = true;
    
    
    user.save(function(err){
    
    if (err) {
    req.flash("error", "Error");
    res.redirect('back');
    
    } else {
    
    req.logout();
    req.login(user, function(err) {
    req.flash("success", "Success" );
    res.redirect('/complete')
    
    });
    }
    });
    });

//note: error handling removed to shorten code. Errors are logged.
```

Comment: What does `done(err)` do? Also there is syntax error in your code. Is this the actual code?

Comment: Shortened a bit. Errors are logged (not shown)

Comment: Do you have an index on `username`? If not, this could be a source of slowness. Other than that I would suggest to annotate your code with duration logging and see where time is spent. This way you can confirm if it's Heroku setup or code related.

Comment: Thanks @Miha! Can you give me an example of how to add an index on username and an example of how to log duration as an Answer?

Comment: @Mihai if so I will award you the bounty